# Youtube upload - how to limit upload speed

Tags: c#, api, youtube

**How can I limit speed upload video on youtube because when i start upload my internet extremely slow down**

```
YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("example app", developerKey, Login, Passw);

YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);

Video newVideo = new Video();

newVideo.Title = Title;
newVideo.Keywords = Tags;
newVideo.Description = Description;
newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource(@PathVideo, "video/quicktime");
newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Howto", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;

request.Upload(newVideo);
```